# How to keep html5 video from allowing display to sleep on OSX

Tags: html5-video

I have a webpage with html5 video displaying an HLS video in Safari on OSX.  When I click the full screen button the video plays in full screen, but the screen dims according to my OSX display settings after 1 minute of being idle, no keyboard or mouse interaction.

This does not happen if I play an mp4 video file from the local disk directly using Quicktime in full screen.  In this case Quicktime is doing something to tell OSX not to listen to the idle-timeout.

My question is how can I make the html5 video page keep the screen from idle-dimming while playing the video in full screen on OSX (or any platform, if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in safari 5.1.4. Release notes are available [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5142).

> Fix an issue that could cause the screen to dim while watching HTML5 video